# How do I store data in entities text-list and field-collections?

Tags: 7, entities

I have retrieved data from an external database using REST.
Now that it is cached in my Drupal 7 site in tables, I need to create new nodes of a specific content type. Works fine for most fields (e.g., text), but...
How do I (using JavaScript) insert data into a text-list field? And, into field-collection fields?

Comment: With [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or some other tool, try doing a GET on your node and see how json is structured.

Comment: @No-Sssweat From Postman: Did not show JSON (Unexpected '<'), only XML or HTML.